# Filling a column with NA, based on the value in an another column

Tags: r, dataframe

Let us say I have a dataframe `df` which has

```
rowID   x   KeyWord
1_u     1   Hello
2_f     1   Hi
4_y     1   You
3_t     1   Guy
6_u     0.8 hut
7_r     0.9 jui
6_i     0.6 jkl
```

I want to fill the Keyword Column with `NA` when the value of `x == 1`. I tried the code

```
> df<- transform(df, Keyword = ifelse(x == 1, NA, KeyWord))
```

For this I got the result as

```
rowID   x   KeyWord
1_u     1   NA
2_f     1   NA
4_y     1   NA
3_t     1   NA
6_u     0.8 6
7_r     0.9 7
6_i     0.6 5
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Thanks for editing..Thats what I am trying. New to R and stackoverflow. So figuring out how to post in the correct format

Comment: Just curious why `df[x==1, ]$KeyWord <- NA` was unsuitable?

Comment: Hi, Take a bit of time and read the tag excerpt before tagging. [tag:dataframes] is for pandas, whereas you need [tag:data.frame] here. Be careful the next time. See this meta post. [Warn \[r\] users from adding \[dataframes\] tag instead of \[data.frame\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318933)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using `as.character` to coerce the result to be what you need?

```
> transform(df, Keyword = ifelse(x == 1, NA, as.character(KeyWord)))
  rowID   x KeyWord Keyword
1   1_u 1.0   Hello    <NA>
2   2_f 1.0      Hi    <NA>
3   4_y 1.0     You    <NA>
4   3_t 1.0     Guy    <NA>
5   6_u 0.8     hut     hut
6   7_r 0.9     jui     jui
7   6_i 0.6     jkl     jkl
```